# What is GROWTH_TEST and appGrowthLog.txt inside of it?

Tags: file-system, android-10, system-apps, system-error, android-11

I recently found the folder GROWTH_TEST on my Samsung phone, and it has the file appGrowthLog.txt in it that says

"com.android.volley.NetworkErrorcom.android.volley.VolleyError: Network Disconnected"

Anyone know what this could be from? I believe it is in emulated storage as I cannot see it by going through the file tree in the files app, only when searching for it.

Thanks!

Comment: "Volley" is a simple Java library for making HTTP(S) network requests. The other term "GROWTH_TEST" is unknown to me.

Comment: Looks like you have found [this XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/weird-folder-in-file-system-growth_test.4015127/). While probably not conclusive, there's [a post by 'soulife' in the same thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/weird-folder-in-file-system-growth_test.4015127/post-85181447) trying to investigate this.